# Check for similar collection withing a collection then add or Update MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

so i am trying to select a specific array from my department-> dStock collection.
i want to select it like i would any other data fields in my initial collection and edit or delete it or simply check for duplicates before adding info.ion.

```
let departmentStock = await Department.findOne({
 departmentName,
 departmentProperty,
 dStock: { itemCode, itemName },
```

i am not sure about the last line
above, here i want to filter by department stock(dStock)
then edit this information and reinsert it or simply update it
});

as shown below dStock is an array of items withing the
department Module.

```
const DepartmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    departmentName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, minlength: 3 },
    dStock: [
      {
        itemCode: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, minlength: 3 },
        itemName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, minlength: 3 },
        itemQty: { type: Number, trim: true },
      },
    ],
    dOpenTime: { type: Date, trim: true, minlength: 4 },
```

This is what i have updated to.

```
try {
  const department = await Department.findOne({
    departmentName,
    departmentProperty,
    dStock: {
      $elemMatch: {
        itemCode,
        itemName,
      },
    },
  });

  if (!department) {
    const newStock = await Department.findOne({
      departmentName,
      departmentProperty,
    });
    newStock.dStock.unshift(newItem);
    await newStock.save();
    res.json(newStock);
  }

  department.updateOne({
    $set: { 'dStock.$.itemQty': 0 },
  });
  await department.save();
  res.json(department);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
  res.status(500).send('Server error!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me,

```
const department = await Department.updateOne(
        {
          departmentName,
          departmentProperty,
          dStock: {
            $elemMatch: {
              itemCode,
              itemName,
            },
          },
        },
        { $set: { 'dStock.$.itemQty': 300 } }
      );
```

now i have an understanding thanks to @user:2282634Joe.

Answer (score 0):

In and update object, you can use the positional operator [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html#update) to refer to the first matching element.

To modify the element, use `$set`:

```
.update({
         departmentName: "Dept 1",
         dStock: {$elemMatch:{
                              itemCode: "code",
                              itemName: "name"
        }}},
        {$set:{ "dStock.$.itemQty": 0 }}
)
```

To remove the element, use `$pull`:

```
.update({
         departmentName: "Dept 1",
        },
        {$pull: {
                 dStock: {$elemMatch:{
                              itemCode: "code",
                              itemName: "name"
                 }}
        }}
)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply please see updated question of what i tried but nothing changed.

Comment: please note i am using a put request.